# Who create HttpServletResponse object for a servlet?

Tags: http, servlets

I am curious to know who create `HttpResponse` object for a servlet, since inside service method we got this as argument which are already instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> who create HTTPResponse object for a servlet

From Java docs [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html)

**The servlet container creates an HttpServletResponse object and passes it as an argument to the servlet's service methods (doGet, doPost, etc).**

```
public interface HttpServletResponse
                     extends ServletResponse
```

Extends the [`ServletResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html) interface to provide HTTP-specific functionality in sending a response. For example, it has methods to access HTTP headers and cookies.

```
public interface ServletResponse
```

Defines an object to assist a servlet in sending a response to the client. **The servlet container creates a ServletResponse object and passes it as an argument to the servlet's service method.**

Answer (score 1):

Servlet is created either when URL is initiated or when your server(servlet container) starts. The servlet container creates an HttpServletResponse object and passes it as an argument to the servlet's service methods.